# Cache won't set values

Tags: python, django, caching

i'm currently working on a website that needs large calculations data. To make it viable I made a Celeryd task and sent a request with all data needed to make the numbers only times to times.

But for some reason my cache won't save.

```
def calculate_members(request, members, clients, website):
    """
    Counts how many members are subscribed depending on lib_drv
    """
    merged = pandas.merge(members, clients, left_on='member_id', right_on='client', how='inner')
    cache.set('%s-drv_stat' % website.program.pk, merged['lib_drv'].value_counts(), 10)
    cache.set('coucou', 'salut', 500)
    print cache.get('coucou')
```

Here, printing cache.get('coucou') will print 'None'

Comment: Have you verified that memcached (or whatever cache you are running)s is running and that you have a python caching library installed?

Answer (score 0):

I found the trouble, another contributor to the project had added some strange configuration that happens only on certain times and it was badly set. Everything back to normal.